# Running SendKeys commands from a .lnk (shortcut) with powershell doesn't work

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, sendkeys, shortcut-file

I'm playing around with SendKeys and powershell. I tried to close the active window with SendKeys (ALT + F4) after running a shortcut. I got this working with adding the following command to the Target field of a Windows shortcut(.lnk):

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\user\Documents\TEST\test.ps1"
```

Code in test.ps1:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys("%{F4}")
```

When I run the shortcut the active windows closes. Now I wanted to make this work without .ps1 script. I tried to run the powershell command from the Target field of the shortcut and that didn't work.

The commands I added to the shortcut Target field that didn't work:

```
$ C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys("%{F4}")
$ C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys("%{F4}")"
$ C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys("%{F4}")
$ C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys("%{F4}")
$ C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys("%{F4}")"
$ C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass (New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys("%{F4}")
```

What I'm doing wrong in the commands above? I need to use a different syntax when I run powershell commands from Shortcuts?

Comment: Try wrapping the "code" part of it in `-command "CODE GOES HERE"` e.g. `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('%{F4}')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong in the commands above?

- You're calling `powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), from *outside* PowerShell, such as in the *no-shell* context in which shortcut-file command lines are executed.

  - For *troubleshooting* such command lines, use `-noexit` as the first `powershell.exe` parameter in order to keep the resulting PowerShell session open, which allows you to see any error message.
- The *implied* CLI parameter of `powershell.exe` is `-Command` (`-c`), which treats all subsequent arguments as *tokens of a piece of PowerShell code* to execute.

  - However, any *unquoted* `"` characters are *stripped* beforehand, during PowerShell's *command-line* processing.
  - **In order to pass `"` characters through *as part of a PowerShell command* being passed to the PowerShell CLI via (possibly implied) `-Command` (`-c`), you need to escape them as `\"` (sic)**

Additionally, for full robustness, it is best to pass the *entire* PowerShell command inside a single (unescaped) `"..."` string.

Therefore:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass "(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys(\"%{F4}\")"
```

However, given that, in the context of your PowerShell command, a *single*-quoted string (`'...'`) to represent the key combination `%{F4}` argument will do (and is arguably preferable, given that you only need `"..."` quoting in PowerShell for *string interpolation*), you can simplify to:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass "(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys('%{F4}')"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I need 2 more rep to mark your answer as usefull. I will ask another question to get this points

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer helped, @pwrsheller; my pleasure. I appreciate the thought re up-voting.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the commands you are attempting to execute aren't being passed to the powershell exe correctly.

The below works for me in the terminal and also in the shortcut field:

```
powershell.exe -command "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('%{F4}')"
```

If the command you are attempting to execute does not need to interpolate any variables in its strings etc. (yours does not) then you can test your statements by executing them in a powershell session (Note that i have switched to single quotes `'` for `$wshell.SendKeys('%{F4}')"`). Your examples would yield some errors and so you know it wont work in the shortcut.

and to give an example for the rest of your attempts (full path removed for brevity)

```
powershell.exe -command "(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).SendKeys('%{F4}')"
```

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('%{F4}')"
```